# How can i print all r-permutation with repetition with a given rank?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Hello guys i have a question: i have to search through the r-pemutation with repetition of a given list let's say `{1, 2, 3}` those which have a certain rank.Well i know how to generate all permutations but i'm stuck at the part where i have to check if their rank is equal with the one i choose. I tried to use `Select` function but i don't know what argument should i give to `RankPermutation` so it would work.

```
Select[Tuples[{1, 2, 3} , 3], RankPermutation[] == 2]
```

PS: Sorry if the question is stupid or i am wrong with something but it's only my first week of Wolfram-Mathematica so don't judge me too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Quiet@Needs["Combinatorica`"]

Select[Tuples[{1, 2, 3}, 3], RankPermutation[#] == 2 &]
```

> {{2, 1, 3}}

or using a more longhand form

```
Select[Tuples[{1, 2, 3}, 3], Function[tuple, RankPermutation[tuple] == 2]]
```

> {{2, 1, 3}}

See [Slot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) and [Pure Functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html)